# swift Updating selectors failed and Synchronous remote object proxy returned error. What do they mean?

Tags: swiftui, smooch

My below code seems to work fine but I get lots of console slog in a yellow background. I can't exaplain or understand what it is. Can anybody provide an explanation? If no, why it is shown?

```swift
import SwiftUI
import os
import Smooch

let logger = Logger(subsystem: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!, category: "someCategory")

final class AuthDelegate: NSObject, SKTAuthenticationDelegate {
  func onInvalidToken(_ error: Error, handler completionHandler: @escaping SKTAuthenticationCompletionBlock) {
    // retrieve new token
    print("onInvalidToken triggered... nick")
    completionHandler("fake token")
  }
}

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    init() {
        let settings = SKTSettings(integrationId: "65031cd01b")
        let ad = AuthDelegate()
        settings.authenticationDelegate = ad
        Smooch.initWith(settings)
        logger.log("after Smooch init...")
    }
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Smooch

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundStyle(.tint)
            Text("Hello, world!")
            Button("Press me") {
                print("button pressed")
                // 1. login with token
                let jwtToken = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImtpZCI6ImFwcF82NTA4MDE3ODA0MTAwMGYwNmUyZDJiZDIifQ.eyJzY29wZSI6ImFwcFVzZXIiLCJpYXQiOjE3MDE4MzMxNjYsInVzZXJJZCI6Ijk3ODA1NzQ3LTFkMjAtNGFjMy04MTYyLTQ2NDdiMTg5MmQ0MSIsImV4cCI6MTcwMTgzMzc2Nn0.7ZZ8LHN15UddWlcYnsLXmtaMqYrAHEFc9Y-QqU-vosM"
                Smooch.login("97805747-1d20", jwt: jwtToken )
               
                // 2. show
                Smooch.show()
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

```
Synchronous remote object proxy returned error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain 
Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc
 was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process." 
UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: 
failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process.}


Updating selectors failed with: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099
 "The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc
 was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process." 
UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: 
failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process.}
```

Comment: It familiar with the framework but ad and settings are getting killed right away.